# drag and drop div element not work well

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I've created a simple code to drag and drop div element but not work well.
When you drag the div element quickly to any direction `top`, `left`, `right`, `down`, the mouse cursor will leave the div element, Although I'm still press on the button .

**HTML**

```
<div id="box"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div#box {
  background-color:yellowgreen; 
  width:150px; height:100px; 
  border:1px solid #ffff66; 
  position:relative; 
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var elem = document.getElementById('box');
var PositionX = 0;
var PositionY = 0;
var MouseX = 0
var MouseY = 0;
var mouseDown = false;

elem.onmousedown = function(e) {
    PositionX = elem.offsetLeft;
    PositionY = elem.offsetTop;
    MouseX = e.clientX;
    MouseY = e.clientY;
    mouseDown = true;
};

elem.onmousemove = function(e) {
    if (mouseDown) {
    elem.style.left = PositionX + e.clientX - MouseX + "px";
    elem.style.top = PositionY + e.clientY - MouseY + "px";
  }
};

elem.onmouseover = function(e) {
    elem.style.cursor = 'move';
};

elem.onmouseup = function(e) {
    mouseDown = false;
};
```

[You can see online](http://jsfiddle.net/3EQCp)

Comment: If this is not working correctly for u ,then u may use http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this one line:

```
elem.onmousemove = function(e) {
```

to:

```
document.onmousemove = function(e) {
```

Answer (score 0):

try this hope it would have your work done :

```
var elem= document.getElementbyId('<%=box.ClientID%>');
elem.onmousemove= function(e) {
    if (mouseDown) {
    elem.style.left = PositionX + e.clientX - MouseX + "px";
    elem.style.top = PositionY + e.clientY - MouseY + "px";
  }
};
```